# where should the .bss section of ELF file take in memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory, elf

It is known that .bss section was not stored in the disk, but the .bss section in memory should be initialized to zero. but where should it take in the memory? Is there any information displayed in the ELF header or the Is the .bss section likely to appear next to the data section, or something else??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To know where the bss segment will be in memory, it is sufficient to run `readelf -S program`, and check the *Addr* column on the `.bss` row.

In most cases, you will also see that the initialized data section (`.data`) comes immediately before. That is, you will see that *Addr+Size* of the `.data` section matches the starting address of the `.bss` section.

However, that is not always necessarily the case. These are historical conventions, and the [ELF specification](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) (to be read alongside the platform specific supplement, for instance Chapter 5 in the one covering [32-bit x86 machines](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf)) allows for much more sophisticated configurations, and not all of them are supported by Linux.

For instance, the section may not be called `.bss` at all. The only 2 properties that make a BSS section such are:

1. The section is marked with `SHT_NOBITS` (that is, it takes space in memory but none on the storage) which shows up as `NOBITS` in `readelf`'s output.
2. It maps to a loadable (`PT_LOAD`), readable (`PF_R`), and writeable (`PF_W`) segment. Such a segment is also shorter on storage than it is in memory (`p_filesz` < `p_memsz`).

You can have multiple BSS sections: PowerPC executables may have `.sbss` and `.sbss2` for uninitialized data variables.

Finally, the BSS section is not necessarily adjacent to the data section or the heap. If you check the [Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c) (more in particular the `load_elf_binary` function) you can see that the BSS sections (or more precisely, the [segment](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~mhaungs/archive/paper/node16.html) it maps to) may even be interleaved with code and initialized data. The Linux kernel manages to sort that out.

Answer (score 16):

The BSS is between the data and the heap, as detailed in [this marvelous article](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory).

[image]

You can find out the size of each section using `size`:

```
cnicutar@lemon:~$ size try
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1108     496      16    1620     654 try
```

Comment: yep +1 for that article u posted indeed a great one

Comment: Waiting for all the 64 bit hype to end :-))